# How to migrate this Apache VHost to nginx

Tags: nginx, hosting, microservices

Im relatively new and wanted to test a service on nginx, but I am struggling to convert this Apache config to nginx.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName api.my-site.de

  DocumentRoot /var/www/api.my-site.de/current/public

  <Directory "/var/www/api.my-site.de/current/public">
      AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Options=All,MultiViews Indexes
      Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
      Order deny,allow
      Require all granted
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>

  ServerName api.my-site.de

  DocumentRoot /var/www/api.my-site.de/current/public

  <Directory "/var/www/api.my-site.de/current/public">
      AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Options=All,MultiViews Indexes
      Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
      Order deny,allow
  </Directory>

 SSLEngine on

 SSLCertificateFile           /etc/ssl/private/wildcard.my-site.de.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile     /etc/ssl/private/wildcard.my-site.de.key
 SSLCertificateChainFile  /etc/ssl/private/chain.crt

</VirtualHost>
```

Can someone help here please? As nginx has nothin like the .htaccess I'm no sure what to do with all the tags.

Current draft:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ipv6only=on ssl;

    server_name api.my-site.de

    location / {
        root   /var/www/api.my-site.de/current/public;
    }

    ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/private/wildcard.my-site.de.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/private/wildcard.my-site.de.key;
}
```

Comment: You can put the .htaccess  file in the /var/www/api.my-site.de/current/public directory, and handle any rewrite or others you need there. (if that's what you are having a hard time with). Also, cat the chain and crt into a single file for easier ssl managing. If you have any question or want me to write the server blocks tell me.

Comment: @flaixmani I added my version of the server config, does this looks right? I could not find an option for SSLCertificateChainFile. I omitted the Directory parts for this.

Comment: In nginx there is no SSLCertificateChainFile , what you need to do is to put the crt and the chain in the same file, and reference the file with ssl_certificate. Now that you have a draft I'll try to craft a server block to work (with instructions about the ssl cert too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I like to separate in server blocks different configurations (even when now are the same, you'll love yourself when you come back 2 years later and need to read this).

The ssl certificate:

Nginx reads only 1 crt file, under ssl_certificate, here you need to concatenate your chain and your crt in the same file, more info:

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-ssl-certifcate-chain

So what I would do is:

Copy the certificate somewhere else, for security and not touching anything.

```
sudo cp /etc/ssl/private/wildcard.my-site.de.crt /etc/ssl/private/api-mysite-de.pem
```

And concatenate your chain into the "certificate".

```
sudo cat /etc/ssl/private/chain.crt > /etc/ssl/private/api-mysite-de.pem
```

Then you can set your ssl_certificate to this file for nginx to work.

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ipv6only=on ssl;

    server_name api.my-site.de
    ssl_on;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/private/api-mysite-de.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/private/wildcard.my-site.de.key;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/ssl-api.my-site.de.access.log; 
    error_log /var/log/nginx/ssl-api.my-site.de.cat.error.log;


    location / {
        root   /var/www/api.my-site.de/current/public;
    }


}
```

And here it is the http port 80 configuration.

Leave your .htaccess file into /var/www/api.my-site.de/current/public and it should work correctly.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

    server_name api.my-site.de
    access_log /var/log/nginx/api.my-site.de.access.log; 
    error_log /var/log/nginx/api.my-site.de.cat.error.log;

    #logs are love, logs are life

    location / {
        root   /var/www/api.my-site.de/current/public;
    }

}
```

If you need any further configurations or it shows any error in the logs (I configured them there) commend and I'll try to handle it.

Hope I helped.